# VB 2005 syntax error

Tags: sql, vb.net

can someone help me check for the below coding, I have a syntax error.

I may have missed out some syntax.

```
"WHERE PaymentLedger.JobScheduleGUID = JobSchedule.GUID " & _
                 "AND JobSchedule.CLID = LabourProfile.CLID " & _
                 "AND LabourProfile.CLNationality = 'MALAYSIA' " & _
                 "AND (PaymentLedger.SOCSOEmployerContri > 0  or PaymentLedger.EPFEmployeeContri > 0) " & _
                '"AND (PaymentLedger.Credit > 0) " & _
                 "AND (PaymentLedger.Credit > 0 or PaymentLedger.Debit > 0) " & _
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post more code? It's not clear what the error is based on that code alone.

Comment: Is it a VB syntax error or a SQL syntax error?  If it's VB then post the whole VB statement.  If it's SQL then have you actually looked at the complete SQL or just at the VB that constructs it?

Comment: probably no space before AND, if its SQL... but yeah, give us more detail.

Comment: Sorry guy. Added some coding for more clarification. Yes. It is VB syntax error.

Comment: Remove the last & _ , you aren't adding anything else

Comment: @alexcctan Unfortunately the code is still not enough for us to give any solution, what do you do with the above string and what's the error exactly?

Comment: If you're using that code alone, you're sure to get a syntax error.

Comment: Is the `'` in the line `'"AND (PaymentLedger.Credit > 0) " & _` a typo posting the question, or actually in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at these two lines:

```
            '"AND (PaymentLedger.Credit > 0) " & _
             "AND (PaymentLedger.Credit > 0 or PaymentLedger.Debit > 0) " & _
```

1 - remove the ' on the first one
2 - Remove the & _ on the second one